# reading an NSDictionary with a switch statement

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary

I am trying to figure out (if possible) how to read through NSDictionay key/values with a switch statement instead of a for loop.

currently I am doing this

```
for (id key in seriesData) {

    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [seriesData objectForKey:key]);

}
```

However I would like it to be a switch statement where I look for the key, if the key is found then i put that value into a variable i will use later.

hope this makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C `switch` statement only applies to integer-like keys (which includes `enum`). It is not possible to use `switch` with Objective-C objects, such as those found in an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: oh right... what do you think the best solution would be for this then? if statements inside the for loop?

Comment: For most problems, you would use an `if`. It's hard to say for your specific issue. ObjC offers a lot of dynamic features that can reduce the need for that. But for most simple problems, `if` / `else if` is the correct tool.

Comment: You could use a switch with the `hash` method, that is what it's there for, by the way.

Comment: Be very careful with this. This is not what `hash` is for. For short strings, yes, it'll generally work. But for longer strings that only differ in the middle, it can have a *lot* of collisions. I've personally had this problem when I tried to use `hash` as an easy way to make URLs short and unique. It's the wrong tool for that. `hash` is meant to speed up equality checking. There is no promise that it is collision-resistant. For non-string keys, it can be arbitrarily bad (all the way to making all objects return the same `hash`; I've seen that in real code and it's totally legal).

Comment: okay cool thanks guys.. I have gone with the for loop and if statements trying it now hopefulling it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with using blocks, you could use one the block based enumeration methods enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock for example.

Also, if you're looking to "filter" keys; as in there are specific subset of keys, (keys starting with "A" for example), you could use one of the predicate methods like keysOfEntriesPassingTest.

All of these are documented on the [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference.